# How to add range in contains()?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, contains

Like the question at the above, I need to find whether a list (ArrayList to be specific) contains a certain range of numbers like 1 to 7. How can I include this range in if condition like this `if(list.contains(range))` ?

Comment: By writing a loop that checks if each element of range is contained in list. There is no builtin way of this. Alternatively try to see if the intersection of list range range is exactly equal to range.

Comment: @Gukkey What exactly do you mean with range of number. Do they have to be contiguous?

Comment: @Tigerware , yea I mean a range of numbers that are contiguous, like a range of numbers from one to ten.

Comment: That’s still unclear. Do you mean a) all of the numbers of the specified range must be present at least once or b) at least one of the numbers of the range must be present or c) these numbers must be contained consecutively in ascending order (a sublist) like tested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71349131/2711488)?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of another range elements.

Then you can you use Collections.indexOfSubList(MainList, subList)
It will return the starting index of the list. In case it is not present , it will return -1.

```
 class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<Integer> l  = new ArrayList<>(); 
       for ( int i =0; i<=10; i++)
       {
           l.add(i);
       }
       ArrayList<Integer> l2  = new ArrayList<>(); 
       for ( int i =1; i<=7; i++)
       {
           l2.add(i);
       }
       
       ArrayList<Integer> l3  = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for ( int i =11; i<=13; i++)
       {
           l3.add(i);
       }
       
       int index1=Collections.indexOfSubList(l , l2);
       System.out.println("index is    " + index1);
       
       int index2=Collections.indexOfSubList(l , l3);
       System.out.println("index is    " + index2);
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
 index is    1
index is    -1
```

Comment: This is interesting when one list is indeed a sublist of the other. But what would the result be for other lists like these two: 1,3,5,7,9 and 2,3,5,7?

Comment: in that , case it will return -1., have updated my answer, please check

Comment: Yea it will work, but I wanted to include the range in contains() instead of creating a new for loop or a list or an array so that the time complexity and space complexity will be lesser. Thanks for you answer though, it gave me an another way to check whether a list contains a range of numbers.

Also, it seems like it is not possible to do that as @luk2302 quoted "There is no built in way of this".